# Is adobe flash builder good for android app development?

Tags: java, android, flash

I heard that we can use Adobe Flash Builder to develop apps for android. But I have a doubt, can we create any type of application? are there any limitations to adobe flash applications?

I know flash is good for games and internet applications.

I am confused, which is better for android app creation? Java or Flash?

Comment: I dont think so whatever SDK comes nothing can beat native SDK of the platform

Comment: Do you mean Java is good than Flash ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advantages of using Flash:

- One code base, many (iOS, Android, Blackberry) platforms
- Easy navigation between view (as iOS does not have a hardware back button)
- Good for apps which serve as a front end for RESTful web services
- Supports gestures, camera, vibration, contacts

Disadvantages of using Flash

- Performance takes a hit when you try to do image processing and other heavy stuff
- Cannot access front camera
- Doesn't give you as much control as Java

Advantages of using Java

- Can exploit Android OS to its fullest
- Performance is better in case of complex apps

Disadvantages of using Java

- Cannot use the code-base to target other platforms

IMHO, it depends on the use-case of your app.

Comment: I thought iOS did not support Flash?

Answer (score 1):

> Major disadvantage: Adobe has announced that they will stop
>   developing/supporting Flash on Android

It'll  be a long time before desktop will follow, considering that most users are IE users (Google analytics supported) and remember that IE9 still has VERY limited support for HTML5 where as Flash has 99% global cover on PCs.

So until such time as all browsers have much more HTML5 support, Flash will still be here for a while - whether it's here for good, perhaps not - but Adobe are already creating their new Flash Development tool to output HTML5 as well as SWF files. But like all file types, they will eventually have their day - but it's not yet that time.

Comment: do u have the link where adobe made the announcement, of not supporting flash nemore

Comment: Adobe has only discontinued the "flash player" for android. The android sdk is a different area where they are actively pushing for. The adobe flash builder lets you build flash based apps that do not require "flash player" to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

java with android sdk is 100% and Flash with adobe air is 70%(approx).becase adobe provide same functionality like android sdk useing "Native code" but some functionality that cant allow by flash.

another thin is that version problem.you can continue with 2.2 or higher.

some Broadcasting functionality are not there

**Advantage::**

flash game building are easy and just 2 to 3 step to convert it into apk or iphone formate.

Answer (score 0):

Major disadvantage: Adobe has announced that they will stop developing/supporting Flash on Android. Desktop flash will soon follow. So if you are starting a new project, unless its expected lifetime is fairly short, forget about Flash.

Comment: Adobe has stopped development of the android browser runtime, not the native AIR framework (AS3 to native app cross compilation).